# ThinkingSphinx & Rails 3 - How to create dummy attributes in models for cross model search?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I have about 9 models (more coming soon) which currently have both common & unique sphinx attributes in each - these attributes are used as filters & don't need to be searchable.

Here is an example of some of my models which illustrates the problem:

```
class Ad
  belongs_to :categories

  define_index('ad') do
    has categories.name, :as => :category_name_tags, :facet => true, :type => :string
  end
end

class User
  belongs_to :region
  define_index('ad') do
    #psudocode below 
    has "(SELECT name from categories)", :as => :category_name_tags, :facet => true, :type => :string
  end
end
```

So that I can search like this:

```
results = ThinkingSphinx.search "red car", :with => { :category_name_tags => "autos" }, :classes => [Ad, User]
```

All my non-Ad models need to have an "category_name_tags" attribute defined which will match any "category_name_tags" filters the user specifies when searching - in other-words  these are dummy attributes that should always match all certain filters - they are passive for most models, I want to do this because if these attributes do not exist in my model, then no results from that model will be returned.

Note: I cannot modify the data model used by the client.

Comment: Hi! Did you eventually solved this question?